# Network Topology for Switch Redundancy

Tags: networking

I am trying to improve redundancy we had our main switch go crazy and take down the network.  I am looking to add another switch for redundancy.  I am very unfamiliar with STP and if it is needed in this case, or if there is another way that I should be looking at this.  We are currently using 4 port LAGs, and have VLANs on two of the switched to vSphere.

Current Topology:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J8E4.jpg

Proposed Topology:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XjUD.jpg

Am I headed in the right direction?  Do I need to enable STP in this scenario?  Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can "stack" the 2 proposed "core switches", that would be the easiest thing to setup and would allow for "redundancy.  You would have the same LAG groups but with ports on each physical switch and then a 2 port LAG to the router at the top.

If you can't stack them, then what you are proposing in your proposal pic is more like VRRP or similar.  That takes some pretty decent networking knowledge and the switches have to support such a setup.  It's not a hard thing to get setup, but it will take some planning and decent knowledge on how VRRP works.

A "cheap" alternative based on your pics is:

- make your "redundant switch" simply your cold spare.  Load it up with the same firmware and config as the primary switch and if that switch fails or has issues just physically swap in the cold spare.

But your question sounds like you could be in over your head a little.  If possible, grab a consultant or trusted VAR of your networking equipment (their sales engineers are often happy to help) and work out the best setup for your shop.  In the end, you'll learn something and understand it better.

Comment: So if stack the 2 "core" switches, should I setup LAGS to the workstation switches, and split them 2 ports per stacked switch?  In case of a failure

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need such redundancy? What do you try to accomplish?

Think about connecting the workstations also using doubled links - to different switches. This could quadruple the number of switches :)

Sure, you need the STP or even RSTP to detect loops (you have a lot of them) and temporary disable unused additional links.

Comment: We had the top switch go down last night, and took down the network.

Comment: Typically your "core" switches should be redundant, as your entire network funnels through the core.  Otherwise a single failure will bring down everything.  If your server access/aggregation switches are on their own "tier", they should be redundant as well.  Workstation access switches typically are not critical enough to be redundant, but it is a good practice to have some extra switch ports on adjacent piers so you can manually re-route connections if there is a failure.  Workstation switches may be cheap enough to keep a spare in a closet.